# Filter stops a record from Appearing SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am currently creating a report in SSRS. In order to save the job of creating a load of Stored Procedures I Found some code that would populate my parameter only with results that already exist in the table(i will call it the ID). The idea is I only want the Id values that already appear in the table so that there are not any blank records.

I have some code on my report that is as follows:

```
 Public Shared Function RemoveDups(ByVal items As String) As String

 Dim noDups As New System.Collections.ArrayList() 
 Dim SpStr 

 SpStr = Split(items ,",") 
  For i As Integer=0 To Ubound(Spstr) 

 If Not noDups.Contains(SpStr(i).Trim()) Then

noDups.Add(SpStr(i).Trim()) 

End If
Next

Dim uniqueItems As String() = New String(noDups.Count-1){} 
  noDups.CopyTo(uniqueItems) 

  Return String.Join(",", uniqueItems) 

End Function
```

This is whats in the parameter to get the values:

```
       =Split(Code.RemoveDups(JOIN(Parameters!BU.Value, “,”)), “,”)
```

This gets the ID from the dataset i show from the table and removes all of the duplicated ones.

The Problem I am have is I an ID eg 5 that shows in the parameter but it does not show its data in the table I have created. I have run an sql query and it does have record. The relevant data also appears when the filter is not on the table but not when it is.

Is there anything I can do to solve the problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the dupes in the SQL and don't use the SSRS filter at all.

Comment: Found the issue was the ID has space in at the beginning. still needs optimization those takes like 2mins to load up